# ANTLR grammar not working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I have this grammar below for implementing an `IN` operator taking a list of numbers or strings.

```
grammar listFilterExpr;

listFilterExpr: entityIdNumberListFilter | entityIdStringListFilter;

entityIdNumberProperty
    : 'a.Id'
    | 'c.Id'
    | 'e.Id'
    ;
    
entityIdStringProperty
    : 'f.phone'
    ;

listFilterExpr
    : entityIdNumberListFilter
    | entityIdStringListFilter
    ;

listOperator
    : '$in:'
    ;

entityIdNumberListFilter
 :  entityIdNumberProperty listOperator numberList
 ;

 entityIdStringListFilter
 : entityIdStringProperty listOperator stringList
 ;

 numberList: '[' ID (',' ID)* ']';

 fragment ID: [1-9][0-9]*;

 stringList: '[' STRING (',' STRING)* ']';
 
 STRING
: '"'(ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)*'"'
;

fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;
   
fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;
```

If I try to parse the following input:

`c.Id $in: [1,1]`

Then I get the following error in the parser:

`mismatched input '1' expecting ID`

Please help me to correct this grammar.

> ***Update***

I found this following rule way above in the huge grammar file of my project that might be matching '1' before it gets to match to `ID`:

```
NUMBER
   : '-'? INT ('.' [0-9] +)?
   ;
fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;
```

But, If I write my `ID` rule before `NUMBER` then other things fail, because they have already matched `ID` which should have matched `NUMBER`

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you want `ID` to be a `fragment`.

Comment: Even if I remove `fragment`, it gives me the same error.

Comment: @teenup then you probably did not re-generate the lexer and parser, because it works when `fragment` is removed. Another option is that you removed too much of the rules you just posted, and you have some conflicting lexer rules you didn't pot in your original question. Always post a self-contained example so that other see what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by rici: `ID` should not be a `fragment`. Fragments can only be used by other lexer rules, they will never become a token on their own (and can therefor not be used in parser rules).

Just remove the `fragment` keyword from it: `ID: [1-9][0-9]*;`

[image]

Note that you'll also have to account for spaces. You probably want to skip them:

```
SPACES : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

> ...
> mismatched input '1' expecting ID
> ...

This looks like there's another lexer, besides `ID`, that also matches the input `1` and is defined before `ID`. In that case, have a look at this Q&A: [ANTLR 4.5 - Mismatched Input 'x' expecting 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777778/antlr-4-5-mismatched-input-x-expecting-x)

### EDIT

Because you have the rules ordered like this:

```
NUMBER
   : '-'? INT ('.' [0-9] +)?
   ;

fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;

ID
   : [1-9][0-9]*
   ;
```

the lexer will never create an `ID` token (only `NUMBER` tokens will be created). This is just how ANTLR works: in case of 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first "wins".

In the first place I think it's odd to have an `ID` rule that matches only digits, but, if that's the language you're parsing, OK. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
id     : POS_NUMBER;
number : POS_NUMBER | NEG_NUMBER;

POS_NUMBER : INT ('.' [0-9] +)?;
NEG_NUMBER : '-' POS_NUMBER;

fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;
```

and then instead of `ID`, use `id` in your parser rules. As well as using `number` instead of the `NUMBER` you're using now.

Comment: Thank you. I am going through your answer and will try fixing my project based on it and revert back.

Comment: Learning from this answer, I found what might be conflicting in my grammar and have updated the question above to add the details. If possible, please help to resolve it.

Comment: @teenup checkout my EDIT

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your response. I was able to make it out after studying your initial answer.