# ANTLR4: Matching an identifier but NOT a keyword

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 to lex and parse a string. The string is this:

```
alpha at 3
```

The grammar is as such:

```
access: IDENTIFIER 'at' INT;
IDENTIFIER: [A-Za-z]+;
INT: '-'? ([1-9][0-9]* | [0-9]);
```

However, this ANTLR gives me `line 1:6 mismatched input 'at' expecting 'at'`. I've found that it is because `IDENTIFIER` is a superset of `'at'`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777778/antlr-4-5-mismatched-input-x-expecting-x). So, I tried changing the grammar to this:

```
access: identifier AT INT;
identifier: NAME | ~AT;
NAME: [A-Za-z]+;
INT: '-'? ([1-9][0-9]* | [0-9]);
AT: 'at';
```

However I get an identical error.

How can I match `alpha at 3` where `alpha` is `[A-Za-z]+` while `at` is also in `[A-Za-z]+`?

Comment: Your first version of the grammar does not give me the error (but your second version does).

Comment: If you move `AT` to before `IDENTIFIER` in the second version of the grammar, I think that should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I found in my work with ANTLR4 it was easier to divide my grammer into a seperate lexer and Parser.  This has it's own learning curve.  But the result is that I think about "Tokens" being fed to the parser.   And I can use grun -tokens to see that my tokens are being recognized by the lexer before they get to the parser.  I'm still an ANTLR4 newbie so maybe 2 weeks ahead of your on the learning curve after playing with ANTLR4 off and on for a few years.

So in my Grammer file I would have
myLexer.g4:

```
AT: 'at';
IDENTIFIER: [a-ZA-Z]+;
INT:      -?[0-9]+;
```

myParser.g4:

```
 access: IDENTIFIER AT INT;
```

Beware after you do:

```
 antlr4 myLexer.g4
 antlr4 myParser.g4
 javac *.java
```

The GRUN command to run your parser is not:

```
 grun myParser -tokens access  infile
```

but

```
 grun my -tokens access infile
```

Adding "Parser" to the name always kills me when I split my grammer into seperate lexer/parser g4 files.  I typicaly Use ANTLR4 get mediocre at at, then don't use it for 8-12 months and run into the same issues where I come here to Stack Overflow to get myself back on track.

This will show up in the grun -tokens as an "AT" token specifically.  But as mentioned in the comments the AT needs to come first.

Any case where two rules can match "AT:'at'" is also a legal IDENTIFIER: [a-ZA-Z]+  put the smaller match first.
*ALSO*  I tend to avoid the * greedy matches and use the non greedy *? matches, even though I don't quite have my head around the specific mechanics of how ANTLR4 distinguishes between '*' and '*?'.   Future study for this student.

The other trick you can use is to use parser modes.  I think the maintence overhead and complexity of parser modes is a bit high, but they can provide a work-around hack to solve a problem until you can get your head around a "proper" parsing solution.  Thats how I use them today.  A crutch to get my problem solved and I have //TODO -I need to fix this comments in my grammar.
So if your parsing gets more complex, you could try lexer modes, but I think they are a risky crutch... and you can get far down a time sink rabbit hole with them.  (I think I'm half way down one now).

But I find ANTLR4 is a wonderful parsing tool... although I think I may have been better off just hardcoding 'C'/Perl parsers than learning ANTLR4.  The end result I'm finding is a grammar that can be more powerful I think than my falling back to my old 'C'/'Perl' brute force token readers. And it's orders of magnitude more productive than trying Lexx/Yacc was in the old days.  I never got far enough down that path to consider them useful tools.  ANTLR4 has been way more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The first grammar you mentioned works fine, this is the result:

[image]

The second:

```
access: identifier AT INT;
identifier: NAME | ~AT;
NAME: [A-Za-z]+;
INT: '-'? ([1-9][0-9]* | [0-9]);
AT: 'at';
```

produces indeed the error. This is because `NAME` and  `AT` both  match  the text `"at"`. And because `NAME` is defined before `AT`, a `NAME` token will be  created.

Always be careful with such overlapping tokens: place keywords always above `NAME` or identifier tokens:

```
access: IDENTIFIER AT INT;
AT: 'at';
IDENTIFIER: [A-Za-z]+;
INT: '-'? ([1-9][0-9]* | [0-9]);
```

Note that ANTLR will only look at which rule is defined first when rules match the same amount of characters. So for input like `"atat"`, an `IDENTIFIER` will be created (*not* 2 `AT` tokens!).